# Phone battery rapidly discharges after reboot

Tags: battery, charging

So, what happens is this:
I turn my phone off for the night. The next morning I start it up again, and it's still the at the same percentage. But then, within minutes, it will suddenly start discharging rapidly all the way to 1%. I've tried various amounts of charge: it seems that if my phone is in the 50s or lower when I turn it off at night, this happens. If I turn it off at a higher charge, it's fine.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How old is your phone and the battery? Rapid discharge (without the phone going hot because of high CPU/GPU usage) may indicate that the battery has lost a lot of capacity but the battery estimation by Android has not adapted to the new situation.

Comment: It doesn't go hot, so that fits. I don't know how old it is. The store said it was new, but then when I opened it, someone else was logged into Instagram and Google. So if it really was new, it's a few months old. But I doubt it (I didn't get a new phone at the time cause I live in a country where that is a huge hassle)

Comment: What phone model, manufacturer and Android version is it?

Comment: Version: Android 6.0   Model number: LG-F600L  Manufacturer: LGE

Comment: I used an app to check my battery's health, and it says the battery health is fine.

Comment: LG-F600L was released in 2015, so your phone is at minimum 5-6 years old. Battery problems are very common at that age. No matter what the "battery health" indicator says. Usually the battery drop rate will increase in a way that your phone immediately goes off (which can cause data loss or even make the phone unbootable).

Comment: Thank you! I'll see if I can get a new battery then :-)